# UICollectionView is nil

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController in storyboard which hosts a collectionView which is referenced using a `IBOutlet`. However, now I am placing this inside of a `PageViewController` and referencing it like this, rather than with the use of a seque :

```
let initial = FeedCollectionViewController()
let viewControllers = [initial]
setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The problem is that the `collectionView` is now `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's nil. You built your view controller in storyboard, so you should init it from storyboard. Like this:

```
let tabSb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let tabbarVc = tabSb.instantiateInitialViewController()
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to solve this, it loads fine however, I have the view embedded in a tab bar controller in my storyboard which is now not visible.